# Can someone explain the @RestResource annotation for building a Rest resource?

Tags: 8

I am trying to create a RESTful web service.  Above the class there is the following  comment.

```
/**
 * Represents entities as resources.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "entity",
 *   label = @Translation("Entity"),
 *   serialization_class = "Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity",
 *   deriver = "Drupal\rest\Plugin\Deriver\EntityDeriver",
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/entity/{entity_type}/{entity}",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/entity/{entity_type}"
 *   }
 * )
 *
 * @see \Drupal\rest\Plugin\Derivative\EntityDerivative
 */
```

What does this mean? What is it supposed to do?

I can't find anything useful about this, especially about the uri_paths array.

Answer (score 3):

Annotations are used in Drupal 8 to provide meta data in the same location as the class definition. It was borrowed directly from Symfony which is used in the Drupal 8 core to take advantage of an existing framework. The meta data is contained from the lines between @RestResource( and the closing ). Everything else is treated as a normal php block comment. For example I have a custom REST resource for which the annotation is:

```
/**
 * Provides a resource for database intermed table entries.
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "intermed",
 *   label = @Translation("Intermed content entity standard methods"),
 *   serialization_class = "Drupal\intermed\Entity\Intermed",
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/intermed/{intermed}",
 *     "http://drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/entity/intermed"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

So for this resource intermed is the id and is used in request operations. The canonical form /intermed/{intermed} will be used for operations other than POST which uses /entity/intermed

In the canonical setting the {intermed} denotes a parameter to be passed.

So if I was to send a GET request to site d8beta14.qetm.org as format HAL+JSON for the intermed table entry for which the id was 2:

GET http://d8beta14.qetm.org/intermed/2?_format=hal_json

This GET operation requires three headers: Authorization, Accept, Content-Type

Comment: Awesome thanks. I have my GET request working.  So what is the canonical path is just the path for  PATCH and DELETE?  then for POST I would need to use the other path?  What is the significance of the "http://drupal.org/link-relations/create" link?

Comment: The canonical path for PATCH and DELETE is exactly the same as GET. The path for POST needs /entity/ in front of entity id as mentioned above. The second uri which ends in create is a second uri path used in POST